# How to insert $ before a string with regular expression in VScode?

Tags: regex, visual-studio-code

With this regular expression

[image]

VSCode could replace

```
# W1 blaAAA
# W2 blaBBB
# W3 blaCCC
```

with

```
# W1$ blaAAA
# W2$ blaBBB
# W3$ blaCCC
```

namely, appending a "$" at the end of `W\d{1,2}`.

Now, I am trying to insert "$" before `W\d{1,2}`,

for example, replace "W1" with "$W1", I tried `$$1` and `\$$1`, none of them worked.

Any clue?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Man! You got me stuck for a few minutes. Here's how I have been able to achieve it:

1. Set search regex to `W(\d{1,2})`
2. Change replace to $W$1

Cheers!